# boost::asio::steady_timer expires earlier than expected

Tags: c++, timer, boost-asio

I am developing a network application where every request must timeout if no answer comes back within a delay.

To this end I've been trying and use `boost::asio::steady_timer` along with `async_wait`.
unfortunately I realized the timeout expires too early, and after some tests it appears the timer actually expires after the right delay, but since the construction of the timer, rather than the call of `async_wait`, as was expected.

Considering the following code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>
#include<boost/asio/steady_timer.hpp>
#include<boost/asio/strand.hpp>
using namespace std::literals;
int main(){
    boost::asio::io_context io;
    boost::asio::steady_timer timer{boost::asio::make_strand(io),1s};//desired delay is 1 sec
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1500ms);//timer was created 1.5 s ago
    timer.async_wait([](const boost::system::error_code& ec){
        if(ec!=boost::asio::error::operation_aborted){
            std::cout<<"timeout"<<std::endl;
        }
    });
    io.run();
}
```

compiling into `bin` and running `time bin`:

```
timeout

________________________________________________________
Executed in    1.52 secs      fish           external
   usr time    6.68 millis    0.00 micros    6.68 millis
   sys time   11.31 millis  617.00 micros   10.69 millis
```

As one can see, the binary returns after 1.5s which means the timer timed out immediately. If the `sleep_for` line is commented out, it returns after 1s, as expected.

Is that the normal behavior ?

Comment: That's behaving perfectly as expected. The timer *starts* when you create it (when using that signature), so it's doing exactly what you instructed it to do.

Comment: mmh, all right. Does that mean i am supposed to create a new timer instance right before calling ```async_wait``` ? That's confusing me because then I would have expected the interface to be such that the timer is started in the ctor, instead of offering a method to do it later.
Also I was worried about the cost of creating a new timer all the time

Comment: I can see there is a constructor which does not specifiy a timeout, but then I have to use ```expires_after``` which will cancel every current timer... so I can't queue different timeouts on the same timer ?

Comment: A timer holds no state whatsoever other than the absolute point in time where it counts as expired. So no, you can't queue multiple, overlapping timeouts. However, creating new timers with a `strand` is almost "free" (it's just asking the system "what time is it now?" and then enqueues to the IO context), so there is no reason not to create new timers as required.

Comment: OK then, I will do some tests in this direction, thank you

Answer (score 1):

> This new code is no suprise indeed. As I was telling you, my goal it to be able to queue different timeouts concurrently, and cancel each of them when the corresponding answer arrives from the server. Since the handler is answer agnostic, it is enough to simply cancel them in order if the answer that came corresponds to the oldest request in queue, which I planned to do with cancel_one.

It sounds a bit like you're approaching this from a centralized viewpoint, how you'd write traditional epoll-style loops, where you access all of the state for all of the connections centrally.

In Asio, you'd typically use an object per connection/session and the timeout belongs to it. They will naturally be different instances of the `steady_timer` object`. Which is pretty lightweight.

By hiding the multiplexing logic from view Asio gives you the opportunity to write asynchronous code much more naturally, using futures, callbacks, stackful coroutines or C++20 coroutines - to name a few. It will work just as well if the async work is heterogeneous.

By comparison, the manually centralized approach usually is only manageable for very homogeneous task loads.

> But now I cannot use a unique timer anymore, so either do I have to created lots of timers and store them somewhere, which I fear is costly, or I have to find another way

The backend for `steady_timer` is `deadline_timer_service` which is already exactly what you are after: the centralized machine that multiplexes all the timers in efficient fashion

Comment: Indeed, I finally opted for a decentralized approch after reassuring myself on the lightweightness of the timers. I works just fine now
thank you